# How memory operations are decoded and handled by cpu?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, low-level

When the Decode Unit receives an instruction, are operands of an opcode passed through (in other words do micro-op contain operands)?

For example:
If the DU gets an instruction that reads a word from the memory at address *0x8000* and places it in one of the registers, do generated micro-ops contains this address and passes it to an execution unit where memory read takes place or is the memory referenced earlier?

Comment: What micro-architecture are you asking about?  A classic 5-stage RISC like MIPS?  Or do you mean modern x86 (like Sandybridge-family or Ryzen) since you're talking about micro-ops?  Or a non-pipelined multi-cycle CPU like Z80 or 8086?

Comment: Although in pretty much all pipelined CPUs where tracking a micro-op or instruction through the pipeline is even a thing, yes the immediate displacement goes with the uop until it gets to a load execution unit.  (If the addressing mode had been register-indirect, the decode stage would mark that so the register-read stage would read the appropriate register and send that along for use by a load unit.)

Comment: I forgot to write that i meant x86. Thank for answer.

Comment: So, in x86 micro-ops contain operands(addresses, constans)?

Comment: Yes, any immediate data, and register numbers for register operands.  Intel P6-family (before sandybridge) kept register values right in the uops directly, instead of a separate physical register file. So those old CPUs would read "cold" registers into uops at issue/rename.  But SnB, P4, and AMD CPUs all use a PRF so the scheduler / ROB has a level of indirection.  
 https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/5/

Comment: Agner Fog's microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/) has some details about how uops can pack into the uop cache.  So we can see that instructions with immediates + disp8/disp32 addressing modes might need 2 slots, depending on how large the immediates + displacements actually are.